Is there a theorem package that works with tagpdf?
As described in this post the amsthm package is not compatible with the tagpdf package/project. I browsed the list of supported packages and didn't see a theorem package that is compatible, but I might have missed something.
So, is there a theorem package that is compatible with tagpdf?

no not yet. Only the default definitions in the latex kernel do currently work.

OK got it. I'll try to make that work.

firstaid for amsthm was added in https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/pull/1477 and should be available in the next dev release

With a current latex-dev, there is firstaid code to make amsthm work with the tagging code. There are some open issues with vertical spacing and custom theorem heads in user-defined theorem styles but they will likely be fixed in the next dev release.
For an example, compile the following with lualatex-dev.
\DocumentMetadata
  {
    lang=en-US,
    pdfversion=2.0,
    pdfstandard=ua-2,
    testphase={phase-III,math,table,title,firstaid}
  }
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheoremstyle{break}{}{}{\itshape}{}{\bfseries}{}{\newline}{}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}

\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}

\theoremstyle{break}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}

\begin{document}

\begin{lemma}
Some lemma.
\end{lemma}

\begin{theorem}[My big theorem]
Some theorem.
\end{theorem}

\begin{remark}
Some qualifying remarks.
\end{remark}

\begin{example}[A note for my example]
Some example.
\end{example}

\end{document}

Here's the tag structure in Acrobat:

You can also use ngpdf to convert the pdf to html.

Since it uses amsthm under the hood, the keytheorems package (which, disclaimer, I wrote) is also compatible with tagging except for tcolorbox theorems.
\DocumentMetadata
  {
    lang=en-US,
    pdfversion=2.0,
    pdfstandard=ua-2,
    testphase={phase-III,math,table,title,firstaid}
  }
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{keytheorems}

\newkeytheoremstyle{break}{break}

\newkeytheorem{theorem}
\newkeytheorem{lemma}[sibling=theorem]
\newkeytheorem{remark}[style=remark]
\newkeytheorem{example}[style=break]

\begin{document}

\begin{lemma}
Some lemma.
\end{lemma}

\begin{theorem}[My big theorem]
Some theorem.
\end{theorem}

\begin{remark}
Some qualifying remarks.
\end{remark}

\begin{example}[A note for my example]
Some example.
\end{example}

\end{document}

